# Google GUI Builder position panel on spreadsheet

Tags: user-interface

Google GUI Builder with google spreadsheet. How do you position the GUI panel on the spreadsheet? I tried setStyleAttribute, but it is not working. The width and height works, but I can't position the panel.

```
function doGet() {
  var app =    UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Measures").setStyleAttribute("position","absolute").setStyleAttribute("left", "8px").setStyleAttribute("top", "6px").setHeight(385).setWidth(100);                   
  app.add(app.loadComponent("Measures"));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  }
```

Comment: I found a partial answer at http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/UJ2nqgHwt70/ZA1IhWV1BYUJ